# Images in FTP but URL says page not found

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

So I have been reading all i can for the last 2 hours and have not a solution.

I moved my drupal site from one host to another, all works well minus:

images in the the 'sites/defualt/files' folder are in the FTP and i can priview them there but when got to the URL I just a page not found message.

example image URL: http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/image.jpg
this what's in my code and the path is correct but the image does not show.

Here's what I have checked:

- Clean url's are enabled,
- 'admin/settings/file-system', set to public
- 'admin/settings/file-system', File system path: 'sites/default/files' as it should be
- .htaccess in files folder is set to

`SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006`
`# Options None`
`# Options +FollowSymLinks`

and I have tried it with '#' removed

- I have tried leaving the settings.php `$base_url =""` blank and with my exsample domain
- I have the files folder set to cmod '777'
- Checked the database files table, path is set to 'sites/default/files/imagename.png', which seems right
- image names do not have spaces in them.
- I have been flushing the cache for the testing different settings
- I have run the cron as well.

I don't know what I am missing the files are there, the paths are even correct when i look at the rendered html, but the images are just not showing and the direct urls say 'page not found'

Any Help would be awesome, I thought i had this problem before and solved it but i have no idea I missed.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hhmm, have you checked that all parent folders have at least the execute flag set so that you can browse into them? I think it is safe to set all folders as: 755

Another way to debug this is trying to download other files contained in other folders, e.g. the README in root or some files in the misc/ and modules/ folders.

Comment: Wow! that I feel like a crazy person that worked! I changed the default folder from 744 to 755 and it worked. 

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Yeah, it is not very obvious that a folder must have "executable" in order to be browseable. If a folder also got "read", someone can see all children besides being able to go into the folder.

Answer (score -1):

Just deleted .htaccess file  inside default/files it solved the issue for me..I dont exact lines of code need to be there in .htacces file..

Comment: This "answer" is too vague to be helpful. You should never just delete your .htaccess file if you don't know what the code does!